# Average polygon values for each ZIP code

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

I have a vector polygon feature class that I created from a raster (I did convert raster to polygon). I would like to output a table that averages the polygon values over the entire area of each zip code. For example:

ZIP     Amount
90210     16
90211     14

etc....

Each polygon is about 4km x 4km. I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4.

[image]

Comment: Are the 'polygon values' simply the cell values from the original raster? If so, it might be easier to just perform the analysis on the raster using spatial statistics.

Comment: Yes. Do you know which spatial statistics tool? Would it also allow me to use the zip code layer as the boundary of the averages? Thanks.

Comment: I have added an answer below that should address the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the Spatial Analyst extension in ArcGIS Desktop you can use the [Zonal Statistics as Table tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) to perform this analysis.

**in_zone_data** will be the zip code boundary polygons.

**zone_field** will likely be the integer or string field representing your zip code.

**in_value_raster** will be the raster that you originally converted that contains the values you want to summarize.

Comment: Yes I do have the Spatial Analyst extension. I tried this but it outputs a Raster. Maybe you meant the Zonal Statistics as Table tool? I used that and it looks to be what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The Zonal Statistics as Table tool will give you the output you need. I will update the link in my answer.